# How do I mock two database calls that make the same query but return different parts of a List

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I'm doing a unit test for some of my c# code and I have to use the same mock but return different values. For example, I want to do this in my unit test:

```
[Test]

_mockDatabase.Setup(x => x.Query(It.IsAny<Filter>())).Returns(List[0]).Verifiable();

_mockDatabase.Setup(x => x.Query(It.IsAny<Filter>())).Returns(List[1]).Verifiable();
```

is there a way to get around this without changing my actual code.

Comment: Why do you "have to use the same mock"?

Comment: because I want to call the same function. sorry, I'm still new at unit testing. Can I just create a separate mock for the same function being called?

Comment: If you want to get two different mocked return values, either create two mocks, or rather than setting up `Query()` with `It.IsAny<Filter>`, set it up to return two different return values from two different Filter parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can usually be solved by using `Queue` class (note that `Stack` and similar data structures will work too):

```
var queue = new Queue<string>(new [] { "First query", "Second query" });
// You only need 1 setup call
_mockDatabase
    .Setup(x => x.Query(It.IsAny<Filter>()))
    .Returns(() => queue.Dequeue())
    .Verifiable();
```

Each subsequent call to `Query` will dequeue current element from queue. Calling mock above twice, will produce *"First query"* followed by *"Second query"*.